# Result from 'java -version' does not show in list of programs on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java

Recently I have been having some issues with dependencies in a Java project that I was making. A suggested solution was to use Java 8 and not Java 11. For some reason, I cannot revert back to Java 8 and I don't even remember installing Java 11.

Note: I am able to compile the jar file with Java 8

When I run:

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

The problem is that I don't see this in my list of programs in settings:

- Java 8 Update 241
- Java 8 Update 241 (64-bit)
- Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 221 (64-bit)

I have also looked in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` and `C:\Program Files\Java` and I only see Java 8.

Can someone please help me uninstall Java 11 Runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't see this in my list of programs in settings

It seems you have accidentally installed AdoptOpenJDK.  By default, the installation directory for AdoptOpenJDK, is `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\`.  I have also been able to confirm that AdoptOpenJDK does indeed update the PATH variable.  Finally, I confirmed AdoptOpenJDK, is indeed listed in the list of programs that are installed on the system.

When I installed it on my system, it was listed under the name, `AdoptOpenJDK JDK with Hotspot 11.0.6.10 (x64)`.

[image]
[image]

> Can someone please help me uninstall Java 11 Runtime?

You will need to hit the **Uninstall** button while `AdoptOpenJDK JDK with Hotspot 11.0.6.10 (x64)` is selected within the `Programs and Features` window.

> I have also looked in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Java and C:\Program Files\Java and I only see Java 8.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` is the default installation directory for **Oracle Java JDK`, not`AdoptOpenJDK`

> For some reason, I cannot revert back to Java 8 and I don't even remember installing Java 11.

One can have multiple versions of Java installed.  You could easily fix your build environment by pointing to your Java 8 installation instead of your AdoptOpenJDK installation.  **However, the only way for AdoptOpenJDK to have been installed is if you ran the installer yourself.**  While the installer supports silently being installed, it's unlikely to have been installed in that way, without your knowlege.